# Как вызвать плагин Cordova используя Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cordova

Я пишу приложение на Cordova. Сам вид приложения пишу на Vue.js. Хочу использовать этот [плагин](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin)

Мне нужен этот вызов

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled(function(enabled){
    console.log("Location setting is " + (enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled"));
}, function(error){
    console.error("The following error occurred: "+error);
});
```

Но где бы я его не ставил - мне говорит ошибку, что нету объекта `cordova`.

Как мне правильно сделать? может кто сталкивался с таким?

Comment: Кажется, кордова доступна после deviceready – `document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => { /* cordova */ })`

Comment: а где помещать этот код?